# Input impedance of a GenRad 2512 Spectrum Analyzer

Tags: spectrum-analyzer

Does anyone know the input impedance on the General Radio Model 2512 Spectrum Analyzer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well according to this document on page 351 it's 1Meg Ohm with a shunted 115pF cap.

http://www.scribd.com/doc/66163879/General-Radio-Handbook-of-Noise-Measurement-by-Arnold-P-G-Peterson

[image]